# How to assign a variable values stored in a vector to a series of variable names stored in a character vector in R?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, variable-assignment

I am trying to determine how to assign variable a values stored in a vector to a series of variable names stored in a character vector in R?

Here is a toy example of what I'm trying to do:  I would like to have ultimately have the values 1, 2, and 3, stored in the variables A, B, and C respectively, so that `print(A)` returns `1`, `print(B`) returns `2`, etc.  However, I would like to store the variables `A, B, and C` as character values in a vector called my_variables .  So:

```
my_variables <-c("A", "B", "C")
```

and I have the values 1, 2, 3, stored in a vector called my_values:

```
my_values <-1:3
```

I tried to use this, but it didn't quite work the way I wanted:

```
   assign(my_variables, my_values)
```

This simply assigns `"A" "B" "C"` to the variable my_variables, but nothing is assigned to the variable `A`.

I can accomplish what I want to do with an array, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this with vectorized operations?  Is there a better way to approach this than using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assign` is not vectorized, so you can use `Map` here specifying the environment.

```
Map(function(x, y) assign(x, y, envir = .GlobalEnv), my_variables, my_values)

A
#[1] 1
B
#[1] 2
C
#[1] 3
```

However, it is not a good practice to have such variables in the global environment.

Use a named vector :

```
name_vec <- setNames(my_values, my_variables)
name_vec
#A B C 
#1 2 3
```

Or named list `as.list(name_vec)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
val = 1:3
var = LETTERS[1:3]

l = as.list(val)
names(l) = var
list2env(l, envir = environment())
```